# Failed to store CSRF token in session! Probably sessions are not working properly

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin, token, csrf

While i try to login to phpmyadmin i get this error
'''phpMyAdmin - Error
Failed to store CSRF token in session! Probably sessions are not working properly.'''

I searched here in stackoverflow without finding a working result.

My system is a ubuntu 18 with apache server and php7.4

**What i've tried:**
change path to /tmp
give more permissions to the folder
reinstall phpmyadmin
deleted stored sessions
cleared my browsercache
used other browser (Edge and Firefox)
uses Chrome in anonymous
changed my php.ini multiple times and different ways

What else is left i can do ? Reinstall the whole system ?

Thank you all.

**Update**
changed my session Folder to /tmp. It is writable and listed in php.ini and displayed in php_info().

Comment: make a simple php script like: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', true);session_start();$_SESSION['x']=true;` run it then it (through apache), it will yield what the issue is, then come back if need be and post the error message, also you should be checking the error log before making blind fixes/borks. You should almost never need to change default tmp in php.ini or permissions on /tmp folder.

Answer (score 0):

Salam,
I had this issue on Windows server with IIS.
and the issue was resolved by setting access permission for `IUSER` to `C:\Windows\Temp` folder[image: IUSER access permission]

I had set permission to this folder because the path of variable `session.save_path` in `php.ini` is set to that path:
[image: session.save_path in php.ini]

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem, so I had to install xampp and used phpmyadmin, which was in xampp

Comment: sry, its not a solution. I dont want to install any *ampp while i have a proper mysql server running.

Comment: Martin, i have no solution for you. Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem but it can be solved if you are using PHP as FastCGI with IIS by just using the Non-Thread Safe (NTS) versions of PHP.